# how to select elements in angular 2

Tags: angularjs

I've got a bunch of date inputs (month, day and year) that I want to turn into a single string. I want to grab the values from the respective elements, a la jquery's $(element) or angular 1's $angular(element).

There doesn't seem to be any such selector.

```
<select name="DoBMonth" [(ngModel)]="DoBMonth" class="form-control" (change)="setDaysThisMonth(DoBMonth);updateDoB()" (focus)="editingDoB=true" (blur)="editingDoB = editingDoB && false">
    <option *ngFor="let month of months" [value]="month.value">
        {{month.display}}
    </option>
</select>

<select name="DoBDay" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="DoBDay" (change)="updateDoB()" (focus)="editingDoB=true" (blur)="editingDoB = editingDoB && false">
    <option *ngFor="let day of days" [value]="day">
        {{day}}
    </option>
</select>

<select name="DoBYear" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="DoBYear" (change)="updateDoB()" (focus)="editingDoB=true" (blur)="editingDoB = editingDoB && false">
    <option *ngFor="let year of years" [value]="year">
        {{year}}
    </option>
</select>
```

.

```
 updateDoB(){
    this.DoB = ??('[DoBMonth]') + ??('[DoBDay]') + ??('[DoBYear]')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of options here and it depends on what you are doing, but since `DoB*` is already bound via `ngModel`, you can just use those properties:

```
this.DoB = this.DoBMonth + this.DoBDay + this.DoBYear;
```

You would also be able to do something similar in AngularJS.

If you just want to display it in the template you could use

```
{{DoBMonth + DobDay + DobYear}}
```

...and you wouldn't need `updateDoB`.

If you need to do something with date of birth on form submission, you can get the values from the models on `ngSubmit`. You may also want to use [`FormBuilder`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) which would allow you to get the values in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks. Still getting my head around ng2.